# Number of element inside linked list

Tags: c++, class, count, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I want to save the number of element inside an instance of linked list class object. From the code below everytime I call `addNodeFront()` or `addNodeBack()` function, member variable `len` should be incremented by 1. But, when I run the code, the `getLen` function only return 1, while the linked list has 2 element. What should I fix from the my code?

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
    public:
        int value;
        Node* next;
        
        Node(int value, Node* next) {
            this->value = value;
            this->next = next;
        }
};

class LinkedList {
public:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int len = 0;
    
    LinkedList() {
        this->head = nullptr;
        this->tail = nullptr;
    }
    
    LinkedList(Node* node) {
        this->head = node;
        this->tail = node;
    }

    int getLen() {
        return len;
    }
    
    void addNodeFront(Node* node) {
        if(head==nullptr && tail==nullptr) {
            this->head = node;
            this->tail = node;
            return;
        }
        Node* secondFirst = this->head;
        this->head = node;
        node->next = secondFirst;
        this->len++;
    }
    
    void addNodeBack(Node* node) {
        if(head==nullptr && tail==nullptr) {
            this->head = node;
            this->tail = node;
            return;
        }
        this->tail->next = node;
        this->tail = node;
        this->len++;
    }
    
    void addNodeAfterNode(Node* prevNode, Node* node) {
        if(prevNode == this->tail) {
            this->tail = node;
            prevNode->next = node;
            return;
        }
        node->next = prevNode->next;
        prevNode->next = node;
    }
    
    bool searchVal(int val) const {
        Node* s = this->head;
        while(s != nullptr) {
            if(s->value == val) return true;
            s = s->next;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    void deleteNodeFront() {
        if(this->head==this->tail) {
            this->head = nullptr;
            this->tail = nullptr;
            return;
        }
        this->head = this->head->next;
    }

    void deleteNodeBack() {
        Node* secondLast = this->head;
        if(this->head==this->tail) {
            this->head = nullptr;
            this->tail = nullptr;
            return;
        }
        while(secondLast->next != this->tail) {
            secondLast = secondLast->next;
        }
        secondLast->next = nullptr;
        this->tail = secondLast;
    }

    void deleteNodeMiddle(Node* node) {
        if(node==this->head || node==this->tail) return;
        Node* prevNode = this->head;
        while(prevNode->next != node) {
            prevNode = prevNode->next;
        }
        prevNode->next = prevNode->next->next;
    }
    
    void traverseLinkedList() {
        Node* t = this->head;
        if(head==nullptr && tail==nullptr) std::cout << "Empty Linked List";
        while(t != nullptr) {
            std::cout << t->value << "->";
            t = t->next;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }

};

int main() {
    Node node1(2,nullptr);
    Node node4(4,nullptr);
    LinkedList ls;
    ls.addNodeFront(&node1);
    ls.addNodeFront(&node4);
    std::cout << ls.getLen() << std::endl;
    ls.traverseLinkedList();
}
```

Comment: Did you check the length after adding the first element? Probably should include that in your [mre] to demonstrate that the problem is the second, not first, `addNodeFront`. Oh, and to be thorough, report the length before adding the first node.

Comment: You don't increment `len` when setting the head node. Your constructor taking a node should set `len` to `1` too

Comment: @JaMiT after the first `addNodeFront()` the `len` does not change and only change after the second one.

Comment: @AkhmadZaki -- Note:  You don't need to specify `this->` all over the code.  It just clutters things up and is totally unnecessary.  The second thing is this:  why does `main` need to know about `Nodes`?  All of the things to do with `Node` should be internal to the `LinkedList` class.  Instead, the `addNodeFront` should simply add an integer, and the `LinkedList` internals takes care of the Node management (creating, removing, etc.).

Comment: Found it, I forgot to add len++ in `addNodeFront` when it is adding to an empty linked list (the if statement). Now it is working properly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I add Nodes inside main because I want LinkedList object to accept Nodes object to be added instead of accepting integer value and create nodes inside the linked list class.

Comment: You do know that the code is flawed.  If any of those `Node`s you created in `main` go out of scope, your `LinkedList` class will have Nodes that are invalid.  It makes very little sense to have a class called `LinkedList`, and it doesn't do any sort of management of the Nodes.   Just a rearrangement of the code you have now in `main` will show the issue.

Comment: I know that, I am just confused for method that takes another node from existing linked list object like `addNodeAfterNode` and `deleteNodeMiddle`. How can I use it if pass integer value to Linked List class? @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @AkhmadZaki *"after the first `addNodeFront()` the `len` does not change"* -- and this is incorrect behavior, right? You should ask about the *first* error, not the second. Ask why the length does not change after the first addition, and leave the second addition out of your [mre].

Comment: @JaMiT, I have found the solution, I forgot to add `len++` inside the if statement in the `addFirstNode` function

Comment: @AkhmadZaki You found the solution this time. Great. Don't care. Not my point. Learn to ask better-targeted questions, and you may find solutions faster in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In the following function:

```
LinkedList(Node* node) 
{
    this->head = node;
    this->tail = node;
}
```

Just add one of the following lines:

```
len++; //1
len = 1; //2
```

So the updated function:

```
LinkedList(Node* node) 
{
    this->head = node;
    this->tail = node;

    len++; //1
    len = 1; //2
}
```

This is because as the `head node` and the `tail node` = `node` now, that means there is a node in the linked list, so we should add 1 to len.

Comment: It still does not work after I change it

Comment: You can try `len = 1;`.

Comment: This constructor isn't used in the code so although it is wrong fixing it won't improve the result

Comment: Found it, I forgot to add len++ in `addNodeFront` when it is adding to an empty linked list (the if statement). Now it is working properly.